# bounding box of n glyphs, given individual bboxes and advances

Tags: algorithm, graphics, fonts, 2d

For specific reasons, I'm implementing my own font rendering, and an algorithm to compute the bounding box of a text by using bounding boxes of single glyphs, together with the respective advance, is needed. For clarification see [this illustration](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/Image3.png):

[image]

For every of these *N* glyphs is given the relative bbox relative to the origin (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax), and the advance (pseudocode):

```
int xmin[N], xmax[N], ymin[N], ymax[N], adv[N];
```

I will give the answer myself if noone bites.

Answer (score 1):

For the general case you won't be able to accurately measure a string using just the glyph bounding box and the advance width due to hinting, kerning, and ligatures which will significantly modify the sizes of glyphs and their spacing depending on their position in the string as well as the chosen font size.

The naive way to calculate the string length by iterating the glyphs and adding the advance width and xMin will only be correct for certain fonts at certain sizes and shouldn't be used if at all possible.

The easiest way to get font metrics is to use an established font rendering engine to either directly get the length of the text (if the API exposes that) or render the text to a surface and find the min/max pixel in the X/Y directions.

Comment: You are presupposing that I'm using normal fonts, and that I want to measure a drawing that was made by the usual way. I never said that because it's irrelevant to the question. I cannot accept the canonical answer of how things should be done when my problem is really quite different to what you think it is. I have given all prerequisites and even the (borrowed) picture fits, i.e., no kerning is involved. OTOH, feeding my font info into an "established font rendering engine"  and displaying it would be much more complicated and slower than directly computing the solution.

Comment: I was covering the common case where someone desires to measure a block of text, perhaps by getting metrics on glyphs individually and performing their own calculation.  Clearly my answer is not applicable if you're writing your own glyph layout algorithm that discards many of the industry-standard features such as kerning and hinting.  I suggest editing your question to note this fact since anyone familiar with glyph layout would have similar comments to mine.

Comment: OK, I have clarified my motivation